# Trying to authenticate using LinkedIn authentication in my iOS app

Tags: ios, swift, authentication, linkedin-api

I have executed the steps as mentioned on the LinkedIn website for authentication and trying out the sample app

```
failed for URL: "linkedin://authorize" - error: 
"This app is not allowed to query for scheme linked"
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.
Goal is to authenticate using **LinkedIn** credentials in the app I am building

Comment: have a look at:  
1) http://stackoverflow.com/q/33602928/1804181  
2) http://stackoverflow.com/q/33578327/1804181  and   
3) http://stackoverflow.com/q/34304480/1804181  
It's the same solution whereby you utilise OAuth2 via your app to authenticate without the need for their app specifically.

Answer (score 2):

Xcode 7 / iOS 9 solution:
Go into your Info.plist and add an array with the key `LSApplicationQueriesSchemes` The array should contain any url schemes that your app needs to use.  In your case, `linkedin` should be the value

Comment: now I get different error                                                                              2015-09-06 19:54:21.951 sampleapp[35300:1243034] -canOpenURL: failed for URL: "linkedin://authorize" - error: "(null)"

Comment: What's the line of code that causes that?

Comment: @Sandeep 
       `code`LISDKSessionManager.createSessionWithAuth([LISDK_BASIC_PROFILE_PERMISSION],
            state: nil, showGoToAppStoreDialog: true, successBlock: {
                (result) ->() in
             let accessToken = LISDKSessionManager.sharedInstance().session.accessToken
            print(accessToken)
            }, errorBlock:{
                error ->() in
                print(error.description)
        })
    }`code` is the function which I am using  and have added linkedin-sdk2 and linkedin in info.plist file as suggested by Tillison.try this and this should work

Comment: @dead_soldier
Check in what thread do you run code. It should be main.