# Single Sign On authentication in IOS requires LinkedIn App

Tags: ios, mobile, sdk, linkedin-api

We've migrated to the latest LinkedIn IOS SDK which only supports single sign-on (SSO) authentication, in conjunction with the official LinkedIn mobile application. Our app works really well with this, however Apple will not approve our latest version, because it requires the LinkedIn app to be installed for the authentication to work.

We need a solution which handles the scenario when the LinkedIn app is not present, to use web authentication, however LinkedIn are very specific stating Mobile SDK-enabled applications require the official LinkedIn iOS app to be installed on the device to function properly" https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/ios-sdk - The Mobile SDK was released in July, so presume we are not alone in having our app rejected by Apple approvals.

Comment: What is LinkedIn's official response to this? The fact they're insisting this is the way it's done, yet Apple aren't approving such apps, means someone is going to have to budge. My thinking is it's not going to be Apple :/

Comment: Haven't got a response from LinkedIn as yet. I do find it difficult to believe all apps created with the new SDK since July have been rejected by Apple.

Comment: also, from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33013704/app-approval-apple-linkedin-oauth-test-credentials this person was able to provide test credentials to an account but he got a location based error. Perhaps find the/a setting that will allow a signon from different locations. Or simply ensure you're totally logged out of everywhere else

Answer (score 1):

Could you test for the presence of the linked-in app:

- if it is not there: implement OAuth2 directly through your app
- if it is there: use it or your OAuth2 implementation (which you'd probably err on the side of using their app for the link-ability between any features of the app you may need in yours).

Thereby avoiding the REQUIREMENT to have the app installed.

Researching for this I did find:

> **Mobile vs server-side access tokens**
>
> Presently, there is no mechanism available to exchange them.  If you
> require tokens that can be used in both the mobile and server-side
> environment, you will need to implement a traditional OAuth 2.0
> solution within your iOS environment to acquire tokens that can be
> leveraged in both situations.

from: https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/ios-sdk-auth

which suggests that authentication away from the app is supported.

Comment: from the link I've provided and in the one you have above, have you checked (and re-checked) that you have completed every step in the chain? I only ask this on the off chance those pages contain updated information that they've added since iOS9 that you may not have yet implemented in your app.

Comment: Thanks for this Madivad - will look into the feasibility of detecting if the LinkedIn app is installed and when it's not (which in practice would be rare) to revert to traditional OAuth 2.0 - will let you know how we get on

Answer (score 0):

Pleased to confirm that the solution kindly suggested by Madivad of using the new LinkedIn SDK if the LinkedIn app is installed and when it's not reverting to traditional OAuth 2.0 works fine. Apple are also back on our Christmas card list as they approved this latest version today within 40 minutes of submission:) Thanks Madivad for helping out with this.

Comment: That's excellent, pleased to hear that, I was a bit doubtful if it would work to be honest since everywhere else I'd read that LinkedIn were making the app a requirement. A bt hard if Apple says that's not going to be the case lol... Anyway, I'd appreciate an upvote and accepted answer on my answer when you get the time :) Cheers.